# C# - loop makes my app not work propely

Tags: c#, loops, switch-statement

I have this app that I'm writing in C# just for practice purposes, this is the code,

```
using System;

namespace Stock_Control
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int qty, index;
        string name, location, code;

        Item item = new Item();
        ConsoleKeyInfo opt;
        do
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("******************** STOCK CONTROL SOFTWARE *********************");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Chose a option:");
            Console.WriteLine("1 - Add item.");
            Console.WriteLine("2 - View Stock.");
            Console.WriteLine("3 - Remove item.");
            Console.WriteLine("4 - Press 'Escape' to exit.");

            opt = Console.ReadKey(true);

            switch (opt.KeyChar.ToString())
            {
                case "1":
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.Write("Enter the item code:");
                    code = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("Enter the item quantity:");
                    qty = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.Write("Enter the item name:");
                    name = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("Enter the item location:");
                    location = Console.ReadLine();

                    item.add(code, qty, name, location);
                    break;
                case "2":
                    Console.WriteLine("teste");
                    //item.view();
                    break;
                case "3":
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter the index of the item to be removed:");
                    index = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    item.remove(index);
                    break;
            }
        } while (opt.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
    }
  }
}
```

It works fine but for some reason, when i wrapped around a loop, the second case in the switch statement stop working, once i remove the loop everything works fine. I can't figured out whats wrong.

Can someone help me with that?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide the code in question instead of a paste bin.

Comment: put the code here

Comment: You are only reading one key : opt = Console.ReadKey(true);.  opt contains the return also.  So 2nd time through loop you are reading the return and not the key typed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works still just fine but when you added the loop you do your `Console.WriteLine("teste"); item.view();` in case "2" and then immediately start again = clear the console so you do not see anything.